# invalid \x escape Module has no __module_name__ defined

Tags: python, irc

when loading the following (or any python script for xchat version 2.8.9 on 64 bit windows 7):

```
__module_name__ = "test.py"
__module_version__ = "0.666"
__module_description__ = "I AM AN EXPERT PROGRAMMER"

import xchat, random, string, re

def test(word, word_eol, userdata):
    cmd = word[1]
    text = open("E:\\xpy\\nickslol.txt","r")
    for line in text:
        line = line.rstrip("\r\n")
        xchat.command("%s %s" % (cmd, line))
xchat.hook_command("test", test)
```

```
[02:31:14]  ValueError: invalid \x escape
[02:31:14]  Module has no __module_name__ defined
```

Comment: clearly the answer is that your `module_description` should read `"Someone on SO is an expert programmer"` :P just kidding, welcome to SO

Answer (score 0):

Use raw strings for windows pathnames: `r"E:\xpy\nickslol.txt"`

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work, however i've discovered that if I move the python script to different folder, it will work.  Maybe it's the folder name?  I don't understand why tho.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an error within xchat. The script works in the C drive, but not in subfolders.

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\test\\startup.py'
```

Either the single or double backslash should not be there, depending on interpretation. They should definitely be consistent!

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this error. I'm far from an expert programmer, but I realized the problem is the \x in the string.

in python 2.7 (only version I tested)

`x = 'C:\Users\xfolder\Desktop'` # will give an "invalid \x escape"

`x = 'C:\Users\\xfolder\Desktop'` # will work properly (notice the stored value after)

I wish I could expand, but hopefully this is somewhat helpful.